# Google AppEngine tells me that my int is not an int

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The relevant part of the code:

```
pk = int(pk)                              
logging.info('pk: %r :: %s', pk, type(pk))
instance = models.Model.get_by_id(int(pk))
```

The output from the log message above

```
pk: 757347 :: <type 'int'>
```

The stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 634, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/<myapp>/<version>/scrape.py", line 61, in get
    instance = models.Model.get_by_id(int(pk))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1212, in get_by_id
    return get(keys[0], config=config)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1434, in get
    model = cls1.from_entity(entity)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1350, in from_entity
    instance = cls(None, _from_entity=True, **entity_values)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 890, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 593, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2967, in validate
    % (self.name, type(value).__name__))
BadValueError: Property pk must be an int or long, not a unicode
```

Anyone has an idea if I'm doing something wrong here?

**Note:** removing the `int` from the last line of the code makes no difference (that was the first version).

Also, the code works without a problem on `dev_appserver.py`.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the last line. It is in the logging.info

Comment: Sorry problem is not with the logging. Are you sure that the entity with 757347 id exists in datastore..

Comment: @Abdul Kader: it should return `None` if the item doesn't exist. But I tried deleting the entity aswell and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Also make sure that you're not confusing id with pk. It looks like your model has a property called pk, but you are calling get_by_id(), which will get the entity with id = 757347, which might not be the same as the entity with pk = 757347.

Comment: @Saxon Druce: For ease with some other systems I also have a `pk` IntegerProperty. The `pk` property should be identical to the `id` used by the key. If they are not identical than I have a completely different problem ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your model have a property 'pk', which is now an IntegerProperty(), but was previously a StringProperty(), and the entity with id 757347 was saved with the old version of the model?

Comment: No, but I uploaded the data with the bulkloader so there's a good chance that it was not loaded as an integer, I'll check it and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I've been quite busy. But... your answer was on the dot. It was slightly tricky to delete the items (editing/saving wasn't normally possible) but it worked.
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom validator for your pk IntegerProperty.

I think @saxon-druce has the right idea about what is failing.

You are receiving an entity from datastore and the from_entity function is apply the data from the entity to an initializer for your db.Model.

validate call is from `google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py`

**From SDK**

```
class IntegerProperty(Property):
  """An integer property."""

  def validate(self, value):
    """Validate integer property.

    Returns:
      A valid value.

    Raises:
      BadValueError if value is not an integer or long instance.
    """
    value = super(IntegerProperty, self).validate(value)
    if value is None:
      return value





    if not isinstance(value, (int, long)) or isinstance(value, bool):
      raise BadValueError('Property %s must be an int or long, not a %s'
                          % (self.name, type(value).__name__))
    if value < -0x8000000000000000 or value > 0x7fffffffffffffff:
      raise BadValueError('Property %s must fit in 64 bits' % self.name)
    return value

  data_type = int
```

Create your own trivial validator that attempts to parse an string as an int.
Eventually you would probably want to apply a mapper across all of these entities to bring them all up to the current schema.

The validator is called inside `value = super(IntegerProperty, self).validate(value)`
so the value should be ready to use as an int at the appropriate time.

**Example Validator**

```
def str_int_validator(value):
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        if value.isdigit():
            return int(value)
        else:
            raise db.BadValueError("Property expected str or int got %r" % value)
    else:
        return value

class Foo(db.Model):

    pk = db.IntegerProperty(validator=str_int_validator)
```

This code hasn't been tested.

Comment: Wow, great answer. I'll give it a try soon :)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the custom validator didn't fix the problem. I'm trying to delete the offending rows now since they seem to be corrupted anyway

Comment: The problem was indeed as saxon-druce described it. Thank you for your great answer but I have to give credit where credit is due, saxon-druce was first and this code didn't fix the problem for me. Atleast a +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message after deleting all elements in one entity/table and then trying to upload new values via csv/bulkloader.

The solution was to add the following line

```
import_transform: transform.none_if_empty(int)
```

to the property definition in the yaml file for the bulk loader.